# Countdown timer automaticaly trigger the Submit Button

Tags: javascript, redirect, time, timer, countdowntimer

I am making an Online Exam Project on PHP.

I want the countdown timer to trigger submit button automaticaly when timeout ?

Also if possible, display another div tag below the timer if the timer reaches 1 minute mark.

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration,
    minutes, seconds;
  setInterval(function() {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

    if (--timer < 0) {
      timer = duration;
    }
  }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function() {
  var examTime = 60 * 5,
    display = document.querySelector('#time');
  startTimer(examTime, display);
};
```

```css
#timediv {
  background-color: #003300;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="timediv">Exam ends in <span id="time">05:00</span> minutes!</div>
<form action="samepage.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit Answer Paper" />
</form>
```

Comment: *display another below the timer if the timer reaches 1 minute mark* What does this mean?

Comment: the same timer can be used to indicate when there is 1 minute left I'd think?! Where is the problem? I see no reference in the timer function to the form or an attempt to submit it - is that the issue?

Comment: I don't see any "php". So, is this really a php related question? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope the following will be fairly easy to understand. The question is a little vague when it comes to `" if possible, display another below the timer if the timer reaches 1 minute mark."` so I interpreted that to mean "provide a warning or some sort" to the user when there is 1 minute left in the exam.

The command to submit the form is called when the countdown timer has reached it's designated time - the method is simply `Form.submit()` where `Form` is a reference to the form, derived in whichever manner suits.

FYI - the timer has been modified to a little over 1minute initially so that the effect can be seen without waiting, and waiting and waiting...

Also - in the code here I used `alert` to indicate that time was running out... it would be better to display a message on screen!

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
 var timer = duration;
 var minutes, seconds;
 var warning = 60;
 var ok=false;
 var form=document.forms.exam;
 
 var t=setInterval(function() {
  minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
  seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
  seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

  display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;
  
  if( timer <= warning && !ok ){
   alert('Time is running out.... less than 1 minute to go!');
   ok=true;
  }

  if (--timer <= 0) {
   timer = duration;

   if( !isNaN( t ) )clearInterval( t );
   
   // submit the form...
   form.submit();
  }
 }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function() {
 var examTime = 60 * 1.1;
 var display = document.querySelector('#time');
 startTimer(examTime, display);
};
```

```html
<div id='timediv'>Exam ends in <span id='time'>05:00</span> minutes!</div>
<form name='exam' action='samepage.php' method='post'>
  <input type='text' />
  <input type='submit' value='Submit Answer Paper' />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add this logic to your `startTimer` function:

```js
// ...
if (--timer < 0) {
    document.getElementById("theForm").submit();
    // ...
}
// ...
```

You would have to set the `id` attribute on the `<form>` to `theForm`.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `setInterval` callback, check if the time has reached 0:

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
  setInterval(function() {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    if (minutes === 0 && seconds === 0) {
      document.querySelector('form').submit()
    }

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

    if (--timer < 0) {
      timer = duration;
    }
  }, 1000);
}'
```

You can display a message the same way but checking whether the minutes equals one.

```
if (minutes === 1 && seconds === 0) {
  // Display an alert or another timer 
}
```